# Special Character Encoding problem in Azure Data factory_V2

Tags: azure-sql-database, special-characters, azure-blob-storage, ssis-2012, adfs2.0

Problem Statement: 
Consider a value “für" is present in a column in csv file (Azure Blob) and when we copy that file using ADFV2 into Azure SQL table, column value now displays like this: "f�r".
These incorrect values are coming up in our business reports.
But at the same when do the same activity using SSIS and copy data to local database, it displays correct value “für".
Is there any way to handle these special characters in ADF_V2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please set encodingName property in the source data set and destination data set as "UTF-8"

Comment: Other encodings available https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

1. Open CSV file in notepad.
2. Click on Save As.
3. Save the CSV file by a name and select Encoding as UTF-8 in the Encoding drop down just left to the Save Button.
4. Save the file.
5. Re-try the ADF part and see for the results.

Regards,

Pratik